# Selecting over multiple relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a podcast application with `Podcast` objects being put together in `List`s. In a `List` there can be multiple `Podcast` objects and a `Podcast` can be member of multiple `List`s. (n:m relation).

In addition to that, `List` objects are grouped in `Group`s, maybe Genres. A `List` can be included in multiple `Group`s and a `Group` can have multiple `List`s.

All the necessary `hasMany` methods are implemented and are basically working fine.

I want to write a Laravel query (currently using `php artisan tinker`) which returns all `Group`s with their `List`s and with all the `Podcast`s per `List`. I know I can do it in a multi-step process, but I'd like to avoid the N+1 problem and get all the information in one go.

Later then, I'll map over the resulting collection and process `Group` by `Group`, in every `Group` then `List` by `List` and for every `List`, I'll show `Podcast` information.

Is it a good idea to get all this information with one query? (If so, how could this be done?) If not, is there a rule of thumb when to use **eager loading** and when to accept the N+1 problem?

I'm quite new to Laravel and do not yet have the gut feeling when to use which technology...

Comment: ```Group::with('list.podcast') ```
try this consept

Comment: i guess you mistyped and you have `belongsToMany` relations and then consider @the_hasanov comment, if not please provide relations code

Comment: both of you are right. There's a typo. And the dot notation is exactly what I was looking for.. Thank you! @the_hasanov, if you add this as answer, I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For eager loading multiple relationships you may use "dot" syntax.

```
Group::with('lists.podcasts')->get();
```